# How do you loop through json when using ajax with php and jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have a `<input>` that displays suggestions when someone types in it. I am building the backend to it so that ajax grabs the first five tags in the database that have that letter sequence and displays it in spans in particular `<div>`. I don't seem to be completely succeeding. This is the first Ajax I have ever done. Help would be greatly appreciated. Below is the applicable HTML, Javascript, and PHP. I think I am close but not exactly sure how to continue. The problem is probably in the javascript.

HTML:

```
<label id="testTagsLabel">Tags:</label>
<input type="text" name="tags" id="testTags" placeholder="Ex: Poem, Edgar Allen Poe">
<div id="tagSuggest">
<ul>
<!--the javascript would add the suggests as list items here-->
</ul>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php #create_set.ajax.php

$tagSuggestions = array();

$currentTag = $_POST['sendTag'];

if (!empty($currentTag)){

require_once (MYSQL); //gets the database connection

$enteredTag = mysqli_real_escape_string ($dbc, $currentTag);

$q = "SELECT name FROM tags WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('$enteredTag'.'*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 5";
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) {//if there are tags that match what the user typed

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

$tag = $row['name'];

$tagSuggestions[] = $tag;

}

echo json_encode($tagSuggestions);

}

}

?>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
      function sendTag(str){
            $.post("../includes/create_set.ajax.php",{ sendTag: str },
            function(data){
                for (var key in data.returnTag) {
                    if(data.returnTag.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                       $('#tagSuggestTag').html('<li class="tagSuggestTag">' + data.returnTag + "<li>");
                    }
                }
            }, "json");

      }

      $('#testTags').keyup(//on key press in tag field show the send the request and show the suggestions
         function(){
            sendTag($(this).val());
            $('#tagSuggest').show();
         });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what `data.returnTag` should be, data is a simple array.

So you can iterate over it using

```
for(var i =0;i<data.length;++i)
```

and access the items inside the loop via `data[i]`

```
$('<li class="tagSuggestTag"/>').appendTo('#tagSuggestTag ul').text(data[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this right, you are basically appending one same `<li>` through every pass in the loop. This seems to be the problematic bit:

```
for (var key in data.returnTag) {
    if(data.returnTag.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        $('#tagSuggestTag').html('<li class="tagSuggestTag">' + data.returnTag + "<li>");
    }
}
```

In this bit of code, you take the `#tagSuggestTag`, which I assume is the suggest box that should hold the list of suggestions, and you replace it's HTML content with a single `<li>`. And you do this every pass of the loop. If I'm right, you should end up with only 1 item in the suggest box. To fix this, use `.append()` instead of `.html()`. Also, your suggest box selector (ID) seems to be wrong.

Example:

```
for (var key in data) {
    $('#tagSuggest ul').apend('<li class="tagSuggestTag">' + data[key] + "<li>");
}
```

Also note that you were calling the returned value wrong. when getting the value from your response object, you were calling `data.returnTag` which doesn't exist, because `data` in your case is an array of objects. So instead, you should iterate over `data`, not `data.returnTag` and access the properties with `data[key]`.

It's quite possible that there is more issues than this though.